# What's the most efficient way to compare 2 elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code to make txtKeyword input to have focus when the user presses a key.

```
var txtKeyword = document.getElementById("txtKeyword");
...
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if(event.srcElement == txtKeyword)
    {
        return;
    }
    txtKeyword.focus();
}
```

I need to compare the elements to know if the message sender is the element on which I want to focus fail.

```
event.srcElement == txtKeyword
event.srcElement.id == "txtKeyword"
event.srcElement === txtKeyword
```

These comparison which is faster?
Considering id is a string, if the element's id is long, this way would not a ideal way.

Comment: First, what has led you to search out such an optimization? This appears to be a micro-optimization with little to no real-world implication unless you've solving a known issue. Second, have you considered adding an event handler directly to the input and "canceling" the event immediately on that element before it bubbles up to the document?

Comment: why not to compare with unique attribute such as `id`  instead of comparing the whole element?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the last one should be the fastest because it doesn't do any coercion.